# SQL Server Collation to match Java case insensitive Unicode compare

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, unicode, collation

I've been reading a lot about collations and have tried a few different things, but I can't seem to get the results I want.

I'm looking for a collation that is case insensitive, accent sensitive, but places all characters with accents after all the "regular" characters.  For example, I want a result like this:

- "a.O. Ark"
- "A.O. Smith Electrical Products Company"
- "A.Z. Vesalius"
- "A.ö.BKH St. Johann/ Tirol"

Latin1_General_BIN treats accents the way I want it, but it's case sensitive.

Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS, and Latin1_General_CI_AI all return this:

- "a.O. Ark"
- "A.O. Smith Electrical Products Company"
- "A.ö.BKH St. Johann/ Tirol"
- "A.Z. Vesalius"

Is there such a collation?

Comment: What does Latin1_General_CI_AS give you?

Comment: @Love2Learn Latin1_General_CI_AS, SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS, and Latin1_General_CI_AI all give the same result as above.

Comment: As a workaround, you could order by `UPPER(str)`, and use `Latin1_General_BIN` collation ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e4c7/22)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to this question is "No" - there is no collation that orders characters the way you want.

> A collation encodes the rules governing the proper use of characters
>   for either a language, such as Greek or Polish, or an alphabet, such
>   as Latin1_General (the Latin alphabet used by western European
>   languages).

What you want is not unreasonable, but it does not reflect any language or alphabet that has been modeled by a current SQL Server collation.

As noted by @dasblinkenlight you could `ORDER BY (UPPER(str) collate Latin1_General_BIN)` to get the order you describe.

Comment: Thanks, this was a while ago when I was writing some tests for an ODBC driver. Although I don't really need this anymore, I do believe this is the right answer :)